# Joomla 3 Articles Category module override with category image and description

Tags: joomla, module, overriding, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I've recently bumped into a problem when wanting to display a certain category (or subcategories) with its children articles, while including the category description and image. The module normally used for this is Articles Category.

What I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Example of good layout]
But what I'm actually ending up with:

[image: Example of real output]
When trying to call the category description or image I get errors while they have not been stored, only the category name and its items (not even a link to the category)

Any idea if there is an override possibility to make this work, or another module that does the trick?

The default file for mod_articles_category in Joomla 3.0.3: http://pastebin.com/8pNeQyzn

Comment: Is this layout being done in a template override? If so can you include the code please?

Comment: It was originally done in the core files but I was looking for an override possibility. Have found it though, check the updated answer

Comment: Your updated answer shouldn't be the simplest way of doing it! It should be a lot more straightforward Can you paste the full default.php file (before these db changes) please?

Comment: This is the default template file for mod_articles_category: http://pastebin.com/8pNeQyzn

Comment: Right so your problem is that your using the Articles Category Module. To display sub-categories you should be using Articles CategorIES - the description. I believe then the description of the categories is then a parameter :)

Comment: It is, but then the articles don't show up. I want Categories and Articles, like in the screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLVED:

Create an override of mod_articles_category/tmpl/default.php
Look for this line in mod_articles_category/default.php:

```
<?php foreach ($list as $group_name => $group) : ?>
```

And add the following below it:

```
<?php
    // Get a db connection.
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    // Create a new query object.
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query
        ->select(array('title, description, params'))
        ->from('#__categories')
        ->where('title = \''.$group_name.'\'')
        ->where('extension = \'com_content\'')
        ->where('published = \'1\'');
    // Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
    $db->setQuery($query);
    // Load the result(1) as an object.
    $cat = $db->loadObject();
    $catparams = json_decode($cat->params);
?>
```

Now you can access the title, description and category parameters (including the image) by echoing the fields, for example:

```
<?= $cat->description ?>
```

or

```
<?= ($catparams->image) ? $catparams->image : "No image"; ?>
```

After I accepted there wouldn't be an easy way to do this, I found this pretty quickly.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, I have used this to make a similar change.

Comment: This was helpful, but I had to change ```->where('title = \''.$group_name.'\'')``` to ```->where('title = "'.$group_name.'"')``` to get it working